# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed when import table

Tags: sql, laravel, constraints

I have some question about database structure, laravel orm and constraints.

So first I have some tables(this code is from my DB dump):

```
CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `person_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `worker` (
  `worker_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `hire_date` date NOT NULL,
  `person_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `notes` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `worker_contract` (
  `worker_contract_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `notes` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `worker_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `salary` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `worker_id_boss` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `worker_specialty` (
  `worker_specialty_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `worker_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `notes` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `describe` (
  `describe_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `person_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `describe` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `person`
  MODIFY `person_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=47;

ALTER TABLE `worker`
 MODIFY `worker_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=45;

ALTER TABLE `worker_contact`
 MODIFY `worker_contact_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=2;

ALTER TABLE `describe`
 MODIFY `describe_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;

ALTER TABLE `person`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`);

ALTER TABLE `worker`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`worker_id`),
  ADD KEY `person_id_FK` (`person_id`) USING BTREE;

ALTER TABLE `worker_contract`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`worker_contract_id`),
  ADD KEY `worker_id_FK` (`worker_id`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `person_id_boss_foreign` (`person_id_boss`);

ALTER TABLE `describe`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`describe_id`);

ALTER TABLE `worker_contract`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `worker_id_boss_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`worker_id_boss`) REFERENCES `person` (`person_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `describe`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `person_id_tag_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`) REFERENCES `person` (`person_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

Here is my problem, when I delete person table from databasa and I want to import it without checking foregin key I have `#1005 cannot create 'db'.'person' (Errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")`.

I create migration with Laravels ORM. All id field are the same type and there no mistakes in name fields.
When I remove constraint from DB it works and phpMyAdmin didn't show the relations between models. When I import db dump there is no errors.

When I have describet models in php code, in which place ORM use relations from model class? Only in app place?

When I remove constraints the db efficiency will will get smaller? And is it need?

What I should fix or what here is wrong?

Comment: I don't use foreign keys for my own projects, never needed to. To be honest, chances are  in your particular circumstance you're better off not using them. :)

Comment: But I use all my FK

Answer (score 1):

First, disable FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS

```
DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;'); // disable

//do your import logic

DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;'); //enable
```